# rails routes using picnik with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, paperclip

I've been trying to get picnik to work with paperclip so I can resize and touch up images, however have had some difficulty so far.

I'm a bit confused over the routing, as I get an error:

```
Started POST "/products/3/photos/4" for 208.88.21.57 at Fri Dec 10 14:44:59 -0800 2010

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/products/3/photos/4"):
```

This is when I try to pass the file back from picnik, however simply updating the image title on the same record using the exact same path seems to work fine and uses the exact same routing as above:

```
Started POST "/products/3/photos/4" for 69.149.172.21 at Fri Dec 10 14:52:29 -0800 2010
  Processing by PhotosController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"photo"=>{"title"=>"Front"}, "commit"=>"Update Photo", "product_id"=>"3", "authenticity_token"=>"uZ3dV3BCSm7GvP39U51KCClx2P8gIWktyki/3rnpOIM=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "id"=>"4"}
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
Redirected to http://leatherarts.heroku.com/products/3
Completed 302 Found in 17ms
```

What am I missing?

I ignored the authenticity token in the controller for the update action... btw

Picnik takes a basic params to submit back to by post, my line looks like this:

```
<%= link_to "Edit or Crop", "http://www.picnik.com/service/?_import=img&img=#{@photo.data.url(:original)}&_export=#{url_for(product_photo_url(@product,@photo))}&_export_field=photos_attributes&_export_title=SaveIt&_apikey=617c5c06600b6c21ebf0bc91eafbbae5" %>
```

## Photo Model

```
  has_attached_file :data,
    :storage => 's3',
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3_credentials.yml",
    :bucket => 'leatherarts.com',
    :s3_host_alias => 'leatherarts.com.s3.amazonaws.com',
    :url => ':s3_alias_url',
    :path => "images/products/:product_id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :styles => { :thumb => "60x60#", :small => "200x200>", :medium => "400x400>", :large => "1000x1000>" },
    :default_style => :original,
    :default_url => 'http://leatherarts.com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/records/m1.png',
    :s3_headers => { 'Expires' => 2.months.from_now.httpdate }

    validates_attachment_presence :data
    validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than => 10.megabytes
    validates_attachment_content_type :data, :content_type => ['image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png']
```

UPDATE:

I got past the first problem with a specified PUT in a new route:

```
match 'products/:product_id/photos/:id/picnik' => 'photos#picnik', :as => :picnik
```

but still can't quite get it to all fall together.  It seems to work and save, but it never saves the updated image.

I added this action in my photo controller

```
  def picnik
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.data(params[:data])
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated photo."
      redirect_to product_path(@product)
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

And according to the log it seems to do what it should:

```
Started POST "/products/10/photos/25/picnik" for 208.88.21.59 at Sat Dec 11 08:09:32 -0800 2010
  Processing by PhotosController#picnik as HTML
  Parameters: {"data"=>#<File:/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/RackMultipart20101211-7501-1tdkwuq-0>, "product_id"=>"10", "id"=>"25"}
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-0[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] convert '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-0[0]' -resize "x60" -crop "60x60+15+0" +repage '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-020101211-7501-42lphg-0' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-0[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] convert '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-0[0]' -resize "1000x1000>" '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-020101211-7501-1nskgrl-0' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-0[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] convert '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-0[0]' -resize "400x400>" '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-020101211-7501-fpe5rc-0' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-0[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] convert '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-0[0]' -resize "200x200>" '/home/slugs/372051_88c7fa8_e87f-144ddfc3-a58b-4233-939c-2131aa001145/mnt/tmp/paperclip-reprocess20101211-7501-1fo13g4-020101211-7501-v5e99x-0' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] saving images/products/10/original/DSC_0212.JPG
[paperclip] saving images/products/10/etsy/DSC_0212.JPG
[paperclip] saving images/products/10/thumb/DSC_0212.JPG
[paperclip] saving images/products/10/medium/DSC_0212.JPG
[paperclip] saving images/products/10/small/DSC_0212.JPG
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
Redirected to http://leatherarts.heroku.com/products/10
Completed 302 Found in 1632ms
```

But it's always the same image as before, with no new adjustments from picnik?  I thought maybe it was the S3 Caching, but I created a new size category and it created it with the old image just the same.

Comment: i'm guessing it has something to do with _method needs to be "PUT"?

Comment: maybe the enctype isn't set properly now?